# Ubuntu long boot - docker and Network service lag

Tags: docker, ubuntu, boot, ubuntu-19.04

I've got problem with long boot on ubuntu. It was not visible before I changed my partitions. I deleted swap and extend root with that space, and the swap space I have got from home partition.
Now when I reboot os it will take more than 3 minuts to get to gui. My analyzis and critic-chail makes that response:

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 33.345s
└─multi-user.target @1min 33.344s
  └─docker.service @1min 30.484s +1.079s
    └─containerd.service @1min 30.473s +7ms
      └─network.target @1min 30.466s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1min 30.413s +52ms
          └─dbus.service @1min 30.410s
            └─basic.target @1min 30.382s
              └─sockets.target @1min 30.382s
                └─docker.socket @1min 30.381s +832us
                  └─sysinit.target @1min 30.376s
                    └─systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service @931ms +1.079s
                      └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @777ms
                        └─system.slice @275ms
                          └─-.slice @275ms
➜  workspace systemd-analyze               
Startup finished in 8.814s (firmware) + 5.480s (loader) + 2.884s (kernel) + 3min 626ms (userspace) = 3min 17.806s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 33.345s in userspace
```

I was looking for an answer but still has long booting. Any idea why docker is loading during my boot? And how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It appears that my swap partition was not used by my os. I changed uuid partition in /etc/fstab and it started flying!

Comment: Can you please further explain what you did exactly?